# Vue js datepicker, getting only formatted date portion

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a working instance of Vue Datepicker, which is functional to the point of picking a date and logging it on select within the console.

The problem is that it logs as `Fri Oct 18 2019 15:01:00 GMT-0400` but I need to send the formatted date portion of this like `2019-10-18` only.

This is `vuejs-datepicker` library and I can't seem to get anything to work with this:

```
customFormatter(date) {
  return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
<datepicker :value="date" @selected="CallDateFunction"></datepicker>

date(){
  return {
    date: '',
    ...

CallDateFunction(date){
  console.log(date);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[vuejs-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker)'s `selected` callback is called with either a date object or null.

You can use the following example code to get a string representation of the date only:

```
CallDateFunction(date){
  if (date) {
    const dateString = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    console.log(dateString);
  } else {
    console.log('null date');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The VueDatePicker have a Props to disable TimePicker that is true by default. As `:enableTimePicker="false"`

Solution:

```
    <Datepicker v-model="date" :enableTimePicker="false"></Datepicker>
```

Source: https://vue3datepicker.com/api/props/#enabletimepicker

Comment: It's worked on vue 3

Answer (score 0):

You can format your date with `Date.prototype.toISOString()` method and set it to your data:

```
callDateFunction(rawDate){
  if (rawDate)
    this.formattedDate = rawDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
}
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score -1):

You can use the javascript function

> jsref_toisostring

.

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp)

Its pretty forward:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
```